# Make Gmail default for new contact instead of AT&T Address Book

Tags: contacts, 4.2-jelly-bean

My wife chose AT&T Address Book as the default for her contact storage on her new Motorola Moto-X. I want to change it so that by default her contacts store in Gmail instead of AT&T Address book. I cannot figure out how to switch it. It's Android 4.2.2. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On phonebook settings, mark to show only Google contacts. Unselect SIM card, phone, and other stuff. Now, the default options will be Google.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. There aren't options available as you describe on my wife's AT&T Moto-x